# THREE.OrbitControls: The second parameter "domElement" is now mandatory. OrbitControls.js:19:42 TypeError: scope.domElement is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Was trying to load gltf file was following a youtube tutorial did everything same but still getting this error please help

Getting this error :

> OrbitControls.js:19:42 TypeError: scope.domElement is undefined

```
let scene, camera, renderer;

function init() {

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xdddddd);

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 5000);
  camera.rotation.y = 45 / 180 * Math.PI;
  camera.position.x = 800;
  camera.position.y = 100;
  camera.position.z = 1000;

  controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);
  controls.addEventListener('change', renderer);

  hlight = new THREE.AmbientLight(0x404040, 100);
  scene.add(hlight);

  directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 100);
  directionalLight.position.set(0, 1, 0);
  directionalLight.castShadow = true;
  scene.add(directionalLight);
  light = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
  light.position.set(0, 300, 500);
  scene.add(light);
  light2 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
  light2.position.set(500, 100, 0);
  scene.add(light2);
  light3 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
  light3.position.set(0, 100, -500);
  scene.add(light3);
  light4 = new THREE.PointLight(0xc4c4c4, 10);
  light4.position.set(-500, 300, 500);
  scene.add(light4);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  let loader = new THREE.GLTFLoader();
  loader.load('wolfx.gltf', function(gltf) {
    car = gltf.scene.children[0];
    car.scale.set(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    scene.add(gltf.scene);
    animate();
  });
}

function animate() {
  renderer.render(scene, camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
init();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your OrbitControls contructor is [wrong](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/controls/OrbitControls).

You should provide a dom element for OrbitControls to listen events.

You should call this constructor after initializing the renderer, and change your constructor to this

```
new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

You are probably using an outdated API with a new three.js version.